# What is the best way to selectively server-render in an isomorphic React web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphism, isomorphic-javascript

I want the best performance for a web page with a lot of content. Of particular interest, on a mobile device, I would like users to see content above the fold as quickly as possible, and then for the application to bootstrap as quickly as possible.

I have a variable `isBrowser` which is `true` in the browser environment but `false` in the server environment. Consider the following render function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContentAboveTheFold />
      { isBrowser && <ContentBelowTheFold /> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note that by structuring the `render()` this way, the server has less markup to render, less data is transferred over the wire, and the browser has less markup to render during it's first pass.

This works fine, but in the console React warns

> React attempted to use reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server.

On the server, React renders the markup with a checksum embedded as an attribute in the top-level element (for ex `data-react-checksum="941190765"`). Then on the client, react calculates a checksum after the first render and if it differs from the server's checksum, it throws away the server-generated markup entirely and replaces it with the client-generated markup.

As a workaround, I found that in my top-level component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle method I could schedule the following operation on the next animation frame:

```
componentDidMount() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    appIsMounted = true;
    this.forceUpdate();
  });
}
```

Then I could write my render method like this and react did not generate any warnings about the checksum:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContentAboveTheFold />
      { appIsMounted && <ContentBelowTheFold /> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there any appreciable performance advantage to doing it this way? In either case, the content above the fold will appear just as quickly, right? Is the additional complexity justified?

Comment: I recently had a similar error I couldn't track down immediately. Discovered it was due to the fact that the root node I was rendering to on the server wasn't the same on the client, and thus the checksum warning.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I know exactly why the warning is occurring and I've explained as much in my question. This question is about the performance difference between two approaches, not the warning that one of these approaches generates. IOW, just because the warning is being generated doesn't necessarily mean I'm doing the wrong thing, does it?

Comment: Yes, if the warning is appearing, it's doing unnecessary work on the client and server. So, what I was trying to suggest was that you fix the root problem rather than try to build around the issue. You won't get the best perf if it re-renders the page.

Comment: I still don't think you fully understand the question. For performance reasons, I am purposely trying to render more markup on the client than the server. There is no "root problem" to fix. Notice that my question is about *selectively* rendering markup on the server. I could easily render exactly the same markup if I wanted to, but I don't want to.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Apparently, it's causing a re-render which is affecting the performance, and hence the warning.

Comment: It's 2017 and this is the only thing that seems relevant to "isomorphic react" + "above the fold". My understanding of the question was "is there a benefit to rendering with (outlined method) over ignoring the warning about the checksum, and letting react just re render the entire content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, updating with requestAnimationFrame/setTimeout is the correct way to do it.

I would put it in state, though, rather than using a variable and forceUpdate.

Comment: I used the same soultion , but with *setTimeout* . rquestAnimationFrame is probably better